# Is there a way to make venn diagram with 4 sets representing sum of a value for all intersections instead of counts?

Tags: r

I have a data that looks like this -

| ID | TA1 | TA2 | TA3 | TA4 | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 100 |
| 02 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 400 |
| 03 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 900 |
| 04 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 50 |
| 05 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 100 |

I want a venn diagram for TA1-4 , where sum of weight is represented instead of count of TA. Is there any package that supports this?